# Linux command for finding a particular word and finding its number of occurrences for a particular date

Tags: linux

I have a log files which roll out every day.

I need to find out, the error occurrences for a particular day say (`20/3/2014`)

I need to find out no of occurrences of the word `ERROR` for a particular day or set of days in those log files and also print those errors in a separate file.

And finally mail should be sent with the details of errors.

Comment: You didn't specify the path to the files and the email alias.

Comment: file path will be as /var/log/tomcat/mw in this directory all the log files roll out in the name mw(file name) to mw.40 i.e maximum back up index of 40 files are maintained.

Comment: email alias be as anyone@example.com

Answer (score 0):

egrep can easily lookup for such occurrences and the store them in a file. This expression below will look for the ocurrence of the token error and it will print the line where the token was found.

```
egrep -i "\s*error\s*" your_file > stored_errors_file
```

You can redirect the output of egrep to a file and then count the number of ocurrences with

```
wc -l stored_errors_file
```

I hope it helps

Comment: how can i search for a particular day's errors in those set of files

Comment: Is your file versioned by day? In that case in your_file you can use your file for today, yesteday, 2 days ago, etc. It all depends on how your log files are stored. For instance if you have an structure like 2014/03/03/logfile.txt you could use 2014/03/*/* and then calculate the number of errors for the whole month of March. Or 2014/03/{05,06}/* and then you would compute the number of errors for the 5th and 6th of March.